# Porting C++ project from VS 6.0 to VS 2010 brought to slower code

Tags: visual-studio-2010, code-generation

I ported one project from Visual C++ 6.0 to VS 2010 and found that a critical part of the code (scripting engine) now runs in about three times slower than in was before.
After some research I managed to extract code fragment which seems to cause the slowdown. I minimized it as much as possible, so it ill be easier to reproduce the problem.
The problem is reproduced when assigning a complex class (Variant) which contains another class (String), and the union of several other fields of simple types.

Playing with the example I discovered more "magic":
1. If I comment one of unused (!) class members, the speed increases, and the code finally runs faster than those complied with VS 6.2
2. The same is true if I remove the "union" wrapper"
3. The same is true event if change the value of the filed from 1 to 0

I have no idea what the hell is going on.
I have checked all code generation and optimization switches, but without any success.

The code sample is below:
On my Intel 2.53 GHz CPU this test, compiled under VS 6.2 runs 1.0 second.
Compiled under VS 2010 - 40 seconds
Compiled under VS 2010 with "magic" lines commented - 0.3 seconds.

The problem is reproduces with any optimization switch, but the "Whole program optimization" (/GL) should be disabled. Otherwise this too smart optimizer will know that out test actually does nothing, and the test will run 0 seconds.

```
#include        <windows.h>
#include        <stdio.h>
#include        <stdlib.h>

class String
{
public:
    char    *ptr;
    int     size;

    String() : ptr(NULL), size( 0 ) {};
    ~String() {if ( ptr != NULL ) free( ptr );};
    String& operator=( const String& str2 );
};

String& String::operator=( const String& string2 )
{
    if ( string2.ptr != NULL )
    {
        // This part is never called in our test:
        ptr = (char *)realloc( ptr, string2.size + 1 );
        size = string2.size;
        memcpy( ptr, string2.ptr, size + 1 );
    }
    else if ( ptr != NULL )
    {
        // This part is never called in our test:
        free( ptr );
        ptr = NULL;
        size = 0;
    }

    return *this;
}


struct Date
{
    unsigned short          year;
    unsigned char           month;
    unsigned char           day;
    unsigned char           hour;
    unsigned char           minute;
    unsigned char           second;
    unsigned char           dayOfWeek;
};


class Variant
{
public:
    int             dataType;
    String          valStr; // If we comment this string, the speed is OK!

    // if we drop the 'union' wrapper, the speed is OK!
    union
    {
        __int64     valInteger;

        // if we comment any of these fields, unused in out test, the speed is OK!
        double      valReal;
        bool        valBool;
        Date        valDate;
        void        *valObject;
    };

    Variant() : dataType( 0 ) {};
};


void TestSpeed()
{
    __int64             index;
    Variant             tempVal, tempVal2;

    tempVal.dataType = 3;
    tempVal.valInteger = 1; // If we comment this string, the speed is OK!

    for ( index = 0; index < 200000000; index++ )
    {
        tempVal2 = tempVal;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int         ticks;
    char        str[64];

    ticks = GetTickCount();

    TestSpeed();

    sprintf( str, "%.*f", 1, (double)( GetTickCount() - ticks ) / 1000 );

    MessageBox( NULL, str, "", 0 );

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was rather interesting. First I was unable to reproduce the slow down in release build, only in debug build. Then I turned off SSE2 optimizations and got the same ~40s run time.

The problem seems to be in the compiler generated copy assignment for `Variant`. Without SSE2 it actually does a floating point copy with `fld`/`fstp` instructions because the union contains a double. And with some specific values this apparently is a really expensive operation. The 64-bit integer value `1` maps to `4.940656458412e-324#DEN` which is a denormalized number and I believe this causes problems. When you leave `tempVal.valInteger` uninitialized it may contain a value that works faster.

I did a small test to confirm this:

```
union {
    uint64_t i;
    volatile double d1;
};
i = 0xcccccccccccccccc; //with this value the test takes 0.07 seconds
//i = 1; //change to 1 and now the test takes 36 seconds
volatile double d2;

for(int i=0; i<200000000; ++i)
    d2 = d1;
```

So what you could do is define your own copy assignment for Variant that just does a simple memcpy of the union.

```
Variant& operator=(const Variant& rhs)
{
    dataType = rhs.dataType;
    union UnionType
    {
        __int64     valInteger;
        double      valReal;
        bool        valBool;
        Date        valDate;
        void        *valObject;
    };
    memcpy(&valInteger, &rhs.valInteger, sizeof(UnionType));
    valStr = rhs.valStr;
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: Timo, thank you for your suggestion, I did not search in this direction.

Comment: Now I have found that /fp:strict option also helps.
This is very strange, because I was sure that union is copied by simple byte assignment by default. Now it is clear, that this is not always the case.

But one thing remains unclear to me: why removal of "bool" and "String" members fixes the problem? Probably the compiler generates different code for small and large structures?

Comment: @Boris L: Yeah I don't quite understand the compiler behavior either, cause it's so situational. I actually didn't get the problem until I removed `Date` from the union, and removing `bool` or `void*` has no effect. MS has confirmed it is a bug (http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/238546/incorrect-code-generation-for-union-copy-assignment-in-visual-studio-2005-c-compiler) but why they didn't fix it for VC9 or VC10 is beyond me. Seems to work in VC11 though.